# TV still detected as monitor when off

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I have a desktop computer connected to a monitor via DVI and an Hisense HDTV via HDMI. I have the opposite problem that a lot of people have encountered. Even when I turn my TV off, Windows still sees it as an available monitor.

I want my desktop monitor to go blank and switch to using the TV whenever I turn the TV on. If I unplug the TV or unplug the HDMI cable, I get what I want. But simply turning the TV off doesn't trigger the monitor detection.

Is there some way to make this work automatically?

My current workarounds are to use WIN+P to make the monitors switch, and a sound switcher program to switch the sound to HDMI and back.